# Returning a value from a void function

Tags: c, function, void

I got an idea, that void function does not mean "do not return anything" but return something has unknown type, like `void *` which is pointer that you can use it with any type of data. So I wrote the following code to be sure :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void x_function(void *);
void x_function(void *d)
{
    printf("the integer value of d is %d \n " , *(int *)d );
    printf("the string  value of d is %s \n " , (char *)d );
    printf("the character value of d is %c \n " , *(char *)d );
    printf("the double value of d is %lf \n " , *(double *)d );
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    int x = (int)x_function(520);
    printf("The Value is : %d" , x);
    return 0;
}
```

but the compiler gives an error:

```
error: invalid use of void expression
  int x = (int)x_function(520);
```

So is my idea wrong?
Is void function simply "Function that does not return anything "?

Comment: Yes, you were wrong, as you've now discovered!

Comment: Okay, but know this, although you cannot return a value, you can use `return;` inside a function with the return type `void`. It can be used to prematurely break out of the function, and may become really useful from time to time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your idea is wrong. A `void` function cannot return anything. The reason you can return a `void *` is because, as @JohnBode mentions in the comments, "the language standard specifies that a pointer to `void` may be converted to or from any object pointer type (6.3.2.3/1)". The value of the pointer is pushed on to the stack and then popped off when you return. The result can then be cast to a pointer of any type. With a `void` function, the compiler doesn't expect to have to pop anything off the stack so it doesn't.

Comment: "the size of a pointer is constant, no matter what the type is" -- this is not necessarily true; pointers to different types may have different sizes and representations.

Comment: @JohnBode , i thik that we set the type of a pointer to tell computer , how far it can move from this address , for example if we have int* , it tells the computer to move up to 4 bytes from the starting address , is it ?

Comment: @Learner JohnBode is talking about the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the data to which the pointer points. The amount by which the pointer increments depends on the type to which the pointer points; that's part of the reason why incrementing a `void*` does not make sense.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , is the pointer is just save the starting address of a memory ? so how it can be different ! , and if i wrong please to tell me.... we always Learn ^_^

Comment: @JohnBode didn't know that? Then how can `void*` be cast to anything? Is it the largest size of a pointer?

Comment: @Learner On computers where data memory is separate from the program memory (so called Harvard architecture) you have pointers to data in the data memory and pointers to constant data in the program memory. On some platforms (microcontrollers) you may have 256 bytes of data memory, and 64 KBytes of program memory. The pointer size on such platforms would range from one to three bytes; `void*` will be large enough to fit the largest pointer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , okay that's good , but i want to ask you one more question , how my program know where is it data segment in the memory ?

Comment: @clcto , youre answer is good , but i think that youre answer need to be edited ... thanks

Comment: @Learner Usually, OS "tells" your program where each of its memory segments is located by setting the appropriate registers. This is not universal, though - on some systems that lack OS the program "just knows" where each of its segments is located.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ,  but how this make char* and int* diffrent ! or this is dependent on the location of the data , not the type , for example , the data that save at address 2 , has 1 byte , and the data that save a address 240 has 3 byte ?

Comment: @Learner I didn't say that `char*` and `int*` could have different size. However, `char*` and `const char*` could possibly have different size on some systems.

Comment: @clcto: The [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specifies that a pointer to `void` may be converted to or from any object pointer type (6.3.2.3/1); how that's accomplished is up to the compiler.  It may require a representation change, it may not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right: a void function does not return anything, while a pointer to void can reference any data type.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that it's return something has unknown type

And this is wrong.

When the return type of a function is `void`, it means the function does not return a value.

A program with the following function is invalid in C:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what my compiler give back when compiling

```
t.c: In function ‘x_function’:
t.c:10:5: attention : ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by     default]
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:15:5: attention : passing argument 1 of ‘x_function’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
t.c:4:6: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
t.c:15:5: erreur: utilisation invalide d'expression void
```

So you can't return something when the return type of a function is `void`.

According to the input type, I think that `void *` is not precise, you can pass a `char **` type and convert it to whatever type you want. That's what is done with `args` in the main function to collect your paramerters in command line an give it to your program.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting it wrong. To cast it right, do this:

```
int x = ((int(*)(void*)x_function)(520);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you use pointers in c programming you can return values from void function.